# Xcode not saving full screen size

Tags: xcode, window-manager

Xcode is opening with a window with the height `778px`. If I decrease is height and restart it, it correctly saves and restores the new height, but if I **increase** it to occupy the full screen, it resets to `778px` again.

I tried deleting `com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist` but it opens up with the same incorrect height.

Comment: Might be the dumbest question, but…  have you tried it at 'not quite the full size'… drag it rather than use the green button ?

Comment: @Tetsujin, It's not, I know sometimes this works, but in this case, I tried it and it didn't.

Comment: OK, was worth a try. I'd have a look at the saved.state folder; try trashing that. `~/Library/Saved Application State/` & then presumably com.apple.xcode [but I don't have Xcode on this machine to check]

Comment: It once showed ok and after a restart it went back. There is a file named `windows.plist` but I don't know if it is of any use. Do you want me to upload it here?

Comment: Now, after every restart, it gets smaller and smaller :|

Comment: Safari used to do that for me, just 20px or so smaller every launch. Seems to have stopped since el cap. What OS are you on?

Comment: Well, El Capitan

Comment: & you tried ditching the saved state & saw that it defaulted, after which it refuses to comply past the first launch? If it didn't default, you didn't get the right file...

Comment: It defaulted to fullscreen once, but then it didn't. Those are the right files because after deleting them and opening Xcode, new ones were created in the same location. But maybe the size is saved in another place too, or cached somewhere else.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'new ones were created in the same location' - same location as what? Everything should default once you clean the saved state, new windows will just step out as the system dictates. If anything opens in a custom location, you didn't clear the correct state files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33390/discussion-between-iulian-onofrei-and-tetsujin).